# Cannot import XACML 3,0 policy file inside WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0

Tags: authorization, wso2, xacml, abac, wso2-identity-server

I am getting "***Policy uploading failed. Invalid Entitlement Policy. Policy is not valid according to XACML schema***" message, whenever i am uploading policy in WSO2 identity server. I have wso2is-5.1.0 version. I got this XACML policy from this WSO2 [tutorial](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2012/12/providing-xacml-fine-grained-authorization-webapps/).

The XACML policy is:

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="Entitlement_Filter_Sample_Policy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
      <Target/>
      <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule1">
        <Target>
          <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
              <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">/Entitlement_Sample_WebApp/protected.jsp</AttributeValue>
                <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
              </Match>
              <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">GET</AttributeValue>
                <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
              </Match>
              <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">admin</AttributeValue>
                <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"></AttributeDesignator>
              </Match>
            </AllOf>
          </AnyOf>
        </Target>
      </Rule>
    </Policy>
```

I am not able to get what is the problem in XACML policy.

Comment: How did you try to add the policy? I added the policy without any issue in IS 5.1.0

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne :
To add this policy, I followed below given step -
1. started my wso2is-5.1.0 server.
2. login in wso2is (https://ipaddress:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp) using my credential.
3. In Management Console screen, went to Entitlement -> Policy Administration -> Add New Entitlement Policy -> Import Existing Policy option and here i uploaded my policy. I kept Import Entitlement Policy From setting as FileSystem.
  
when i clicked on upload button, i got "Policy uploading failed. Invalid Entitlement Policy. Policy is not valid according to XACML schema" pop up message.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to successfully import the policy you pasted in your question to the Axiomatics Policy Administration Point. It is a valid XACML 3.0 policy and assuming WSO2 supports XACML 3.0 it should work fine.

[image: Overview of the Policy in the Axiomatics Policy Administration Point]

Comment: I tried to import the same XACML policy in WSO2IS-5.1.0 but i am getting same message "Policy uploading failed. Invalid Entitlement Policy. Policy is not valid according to XACML schema" message".

Comment: Is there a chance you might be importing into a XACML 2.0 store ?

Comment: I am following these steps - 1. started my wso2is-5.1.0 server. 2. login in wso2is (ipaddress:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp) using my credential. 3. In Management Console screen, went to Entitlement -> Policy Administration -> Add New Entitlement Policy -> Import Existing Policy option and here i uploaded my policy. I kept Import Entitlement Policy From setting as FileSystem. when i clicked on upload button, i got "Policy uploading failed. Invalid Entitlement Policy. Policy is not valid according to XACML schema" pop up message. Please let me know, If i am doing any thing wrong.

Comment: As David mentioned, this policy file can import to the WSO2 IS 5.1.0 without any issue. Can you please check the MD5 value of your pack?  MD5 of wso2is-5.1.0.zip should be - "BA 47 33 6E 92 4D 2B 88  1A 94 1F 68 1D BD DF 28"

Answer (score 0):

Your XACML policy is right. I was able to upload it to WSO2 IS 5.1.0.
Have a look at the [screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rML27.png) of the attached XACML Policy.

[image]

Did you try the 'Write Policy in XML option'? See whether you experience the same error after copy pasting your policy into the xml base.