# Not able to import XACML policy in wso2is-5.1.0

Tags: authorization, xacml, xacml3, abac, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to upload below given XACML policy in wso2is-5.1.0. I am getting "***Policy uploading failed. Invalid Entitlement Policy. Policy is not valid according to XACML schema***" error message. I am not able to figure out, what is the problem with my XACML. On console, i found ***[2016-06-20 18:50:06,142] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.EntitlementUtil} -  Invalid Namespace in policy*** message.

```
    <Policy PolicyId="BankUseCasePolicy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy:schema:os">
  <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule_On_Withdrew">
    <Condition>
      <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
        <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
          <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">BankService/withdrew</AttributeValue>
          <ResourceAttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
        </Apply>
        <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
          <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">manager</AttributeValue>
          <SubjectAttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
        </Apply>
      </Apply>
    </Condition>
  </Rule>
  <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule_On_Deposit">
    <Condition>
      <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
        <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
          <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">BankService/deposit</AttributeValue>
          <ResourceAttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
        </Apply>
        <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:or">
          <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">manager</AttributeValue>
            <SubjectAttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
          </Apply>
          <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">executive</AttributeValue>
            <SubjectAttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
          </Apply>
        </Apply>
      </Apply>
    </Condition>
  </Rule>
  <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Deny_Rule"/>
  <Target>
    <Environments>
      <Environment>
        <EnvironmentMatch MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
          <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">wso2.org</AttributeValue>
          <EnvironmentAttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:environment:environment-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
        </EnvironmentMatch>
      </Environment>
    </Environments>
  </Target>
</Policy>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot import XACML 3,0 policy file inside WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812971/cannot-import-xacml-3-0-policy-file-inside-wso2-identity-server-5-1-0)

Comment: @David Brossard

Both questions are different. In above mention problem, I tried to import this policy in wso2is-5.1 and wso2is-5.0 but no luck. I got only "Policy uploading failed. Invalid Entitlement Policy. Policy is not valid according to XACML schema" error message. Please correct me know, If i am missing anything. It is urgent for me.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are failing from the below point [1],  where your schema is null. Your schema is not mapped properly.

Please double check your policy, whether its compatiple with XACML 3.0

[1] https://github.com/wso2-attic/carbon-identity/blob/master/components/entitlement/org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/entitlement/EntitlementUtil.java#L237

Comment: Please edit this to make sure you write in complete sentences; the first sentence is not complete. Please also be sure you say something about what is wrong, not just that it *is* wrong.